# How to define more fine-grained permissions or custom logic for built-in roles in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

Keycloak provides some built-in roles to manage keycloak itself. These roles are defined in the `realm-management` client of every non-master realm. As example, I can define a user which has the permissions to manage users. But now this user can change all the roles of all the users. The user can even change the role of itself.

In our application we need a hierarchical role structure in the following way. We have a `root`, `admin` and some other specific application roles. The `root` role should be able to manage the keycloak customer realm as also some application specific functionality. The `admin` role should have the permissions to manage users and also some application specific functionality.

I have tried to model that in keycloak the following way. I have two realm roles `root` and `admin` as also some client (my-app) roles `root`, `admin`, `edit` and `view`. The realm roles are composite roles which use their counterpart in the client (root -> may-app.root, admin -> my-app.admin).

Now, the issues is that the admin user can change it's role to root. How can I restrict the permissions of the admin user to allow only to manage user or roles that are on the same level or below? Is their such built-in functionality or should I provide my own UI on top of the Keycloak REST API?